# Maintain aspect ratio of an image within a div

Tags: html, image, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to make my own lightbox and something that I can not get over is parent fitting to image, maintaining its ratio. The lightbox idea is that it's supposed to display any image (portrait, landscape) correctly, so this is not a 'wrong image' case.

The case: My parent div fits the portrait-oriented picture's original width while keeping a nice max-height of 90vh. Which results in disorting the picture's ratio.

The project: https://bambi007.github.io/veneer-in-shambles/

The code:

```css
#veneer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #0000008e;
  z-index: 10000;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &.veneer-on {
    display: flex;
  }

  .veneer-image-container {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 90vh;
    max-width: 90vw;

    display: flex;
    border: 10px solid tomato;

    .veneer-image {
      border: 10px solid white;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      // object-fit: contain;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="veneer">
    <div class="veneer-image-container">
      <div id="veneer-close-button" title="close"></div>
      <img class="veneer-image" src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you post some code here

Comment: @JonathanIrwin sure, just edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an algorithm that calculates best width of image container to display the image maintaining its ratio. Probably I will improve it in near future.

```js
if (veneerImage.naturalHeight > veneerImageContainer.offsetHeight) {

      var heightDifference = veneerImage.naturalHeight - veneerImageContainer.offsetHeight
      var percentage = heightDifference / veneerImage.naturalHeight * 100
      var containerWidth = veneerImage.naturalWidth - (veneerImage.naturalWidth / 100 * percentage)
      veneerImageContainer.style.width = containerWidth + 'px';
    }
```